# Download all dtx from CTAN

Tags: ctan, dtx

I've written some code to extract some help from dtx files (documented package), and I have tested it on a few packages for which I had the `.dtx`. It seems, however, that `.dtx` files are not shipped with TeXlive (or rather, `find /usr -name '*.dtx'` only came up with very few of them).

I could simply go to CTAN and download package documentation one file at a time, but... that's not desirable `:)`. So how can I do that in the most efficient possible way?

EDIT: it appears that the absence of dtx is normal under Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid). [Only dtx from the koma-script and a few others are included.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid&searchon=contents&keywords=dtx)

Comment: I guess TeX Live does have (almost) all `.dtx` files in `texmf-dist/source/{latex|generic|...}`. But there are a lot of packages distributed without `.dtx` files, such as `pgf`.

Comment: are you sure you installed *everything* from tex live?  the `.dtx` files are segregated in a `source` tree separate from the "active" trees to save time.  when installing, i believe there's an option to omit the `source` tree to save space.

Comment: @barbara beeton: a search for texlive in my package manager (synaptic) only comes up with various texlive2009 subpackages, all of which are installed.

Comment: Did you try to get the Debian source package for `texlive-base`? http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/texlive-base.  I am not sure, but I think it should have the dtx files in it.  It is a huge file, though, the `rsync` solution is better, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `rsync` interface of the three main archive servers. Then use the correct `rsync` option to only include `.dtx` files:

```
rsync -aP --prune-empty-dirs --include='*/' --include='*.dtx' --exclude='*' rsync://rsync.dante.ctan.org/CTAN alldtxs
```

However, in my manually installed TeXLive2010 tree the DTX files are included.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that I have TeXLive2009 installed?

Comment: @Bruno: The TeXLive provided by Debian or Ubuntu might not have the `source` files installed. You might try to install `texlive-full` with this distributions, but I can't tell you if this will install the `.dtx` files. I strongly recommend you to install TeXLive manually. Then you get the benefit of being able to update packages using `tlmgr`.

Comment: Thank you for your rsync dark magic: it works. I indeed have Ubuntu's `texlive-full` installed, but there is no dtx. I'll give a try to the manual installation.

Comment: @Bruno: If you do make a manual install (which I would recommend), you may want to look at http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html . Note in particular the part about creating an "equivs" package, so that the package manager knows that various (TeX) dependencies are met. Of course, you should uninstall all tex-related packages from the package manager, to avoid interference.

Answer (score 6):

```
find /usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/source/ -name "*.dtx" | nl
```

reports 1315 files

Comment: On my installation, `/usr/local/texlive` does not exist. Everything seems to be under `/usr/share`

Comment: Sure, then you do not have the TexLive from tug.org but from your Linux distribution. However, there  should also be a `???/source/` dir. Which distribution do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu's `texlive-full` (TeXLive 2009). There have been issues in the past apparently that Ubuntu was sticking with TeXLive 2007 when TeXLive 2009 was already out. This at least more or less explains why I don't have TeXLive 2010. On the dtx issue, I don't know. I'll go for Martin Sharrer's idea of trying manual installation.

Comment: sorry for double posting. I found out that Ubuntu's packages (for Lucid) only include 60 or so dtx. See the link in my updated question.

Comment: @Bruno: for Ubuntu/Hardy it was the package `tetex-src` Lucid has indeed no source file package